# Is database close () missing in API Demos LoaderThrottle example?

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

I wasn't able to find any database closing in [LoaderThrottle](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LoaderThrottle.html) example.

Does LoaderManager take care about this or close() method is really missing?